# How to order by count or some conditions from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I've a project that create a q&a website.
I want to show questions by these conditions.
 1. Show by the latest question, yeah i know just order by `created desc`.
 2. Show and sort questions by most answers.
 3. Show and sort questions by most voted. (like most answers) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes).
 4. Show questions where unanswered. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered)

And here is my tables structure in database.

```
TABLE question
COLUMNS
q_id (primary key)
userid
title
content
created

TABLE answer
COLUMNS
a_id (primary key)
userid
q_id
content
created

TABLE vote
COLUMNS
userid
q_id
created
```

And each tables it can have a million of rows.

For my 4 questions above I'm trying these `SQL`(s).
**1 Show by the latest question. (solved)**

```
select * from question order by created desc
```

**2 Show and sort by most answers. (seems to slow)**

```
SELECT q.*, COUNT(a.id) as answerCount
FROM question q
LEFT JOIN answer a
        ON (q.q_id = a.q_id)
ORDER BY answerCount DESC
```

**3 Show and sort by most voted. (seems to slow).**

```
SELECT q.*, COUNT(v.id) as voteCount
FROM question q
LEFT JOIN vote v
        ON (q.q_id = v.q_id)
ORDER BY voteCount DESC
```

**4 Show questions where unanswered. (seems to slow)**

```
SELECT q.* 
    FROM question q
    LEFT JOIN answer a 
        ON p.q_id = a.q_id
    WHERE a.q_id IS NULL ORDER BY q.created DESC
```

Note: If i use `INNER JOIN` the rows where count = 0 will not be selected.

As I think, The other websites are commonly have field to count `answers` and `votes` already? To make it fast and should i change to this or they have some algorithm which no need to count answer and vote in `question` table?

```
TABLE question
COLUMNS
q_id (primary key)
userid
title
content
created
answer_count
votes_count
```

Help or advice will be truly appreciated.

Comment: you can use a left join to select rows where count = 0 and speeding up the process you can add index or go for a stored proc

Answer (score 1):

You can try re-writing your queries, but as MySQL is known for preferring joins over more straight-forward ways, they are not likely to be faster. Here are some queries you can try:

**Show and sort by most answers. Use GROUP BY and COUNT(*) to make it plain what you do.**

```
SELECT q.*, COUNT(*) as answerCount
FROM question q
LEFT JOIN answer a ON a.q_id = q.q_id
GROUP BY q.q_id
ORDER BY answerCount DESC;
```

**Show and sort by most answers. Count in a sub-query.**

```
SELECT q.*, (select count(*) from answers a where a.q_id = q.q_id) as answerCount
FROM question q
ORDER BY answerCount DESC;
```

**Show and sort by most answers. Count in a derived table query.**

```
SELECT q.*, a.answerCount
FROM question q
LEFT JOIN (select q_id, count(*) as answerCount from answers group by q_id) a
  ON a.q_id = q.q_id
ORDER BY a.answerCount DESC;
```

**Show questions where unanswered. I.e. where no answer EXISTS:**

```
SELECT q.*
FROM question q
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from answer a where a.q_id = q.q_id)
ORDER BY q.created DESC;
```

However, as mentioned, these more straight-forward queries are not necessarily faster. Well, you can give them a try anyhow.

So if re-writing the queries doesn't speed things up, then, yes you can add an answer and a vote count to your question table. This is certainly redundant, but if requirements make such a step necessary, then take it.